# C# - SaveChanges() doesn't update the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I tried many solutions found on Stackoverflow but none worked. I have a local database linked with EF Designer.

I'm using Entity Framework to create rows and store them into the database. It's working since `database.SaveChanges();` returns 1 (not zero). Then I loop on the database rows and I can see that data were well saved.

Nonetheless, when I'm closing my console app and refreshing database, I can't find the values I just added and the rows I generated.

Working on this issue since few hours, browsed Internet but none of the answers helped me.

I already tried to do `database.User.Attach()` and `EntityState.Modified` but they didn't work.

I even tried to move my code in a different class, but it didn't work.

```
public static void AddClient(String firstName, String lastName, int phoneNumber, String email, String wishlist)
{
    using (DatabaseEntity database = new DatabaseEntity())
    {
        database.User.Add(new User() {
                First_Name = firstName,
                Last_Name = lastName,
                Phone_Number = phoneNumber,
                Email = email,
                Wishlist = wishlist
            });

        database.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I expected data to be saved in the database after closing app, but they aren't.

Comment: Where is your database?  Are you perhaps using some in-memory database or something that's otherwise lost when the application ends?  Are you doing anything to refresh/re-create the database when the application starts?

Comment: @David my database is in the root project. What do you mean by using some in-memory database ? I'm not doing anything to refresh/re-create the database when it starts. Something that may help, on the left side (server explorer), when I'm debugging, the database gets a red cross. I must click on the "refresh button" to make it connected again

Comment: log or debug the value in DatabaseEntity.Database.Connection.Connectionstring and see which database this context is referring to , make sure it's the same database , make sure that there is no Database Initialization Strategies (dropandcreate , dropandcreateifchanged , etc)

Comment: @Kamil Add your dbContext class please!

Comment: @MostafaELite it's the good database. there are no initialization strategies running. I added manually a row to the DB and I can get it through my code but still can't save changes.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I don't have none

Comment: are correct sql statements issued? your description sounds like you are not targeting the correct database or the database does get restored by some application. What happens when you manually insert new rows into the database and run your application afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

When Visual Studio uses local databases, at each debug it copies the databases and works on the copied.

So, I had to add a new connection on the Server Explorer that was targetting `my_project_path/bin/debug/database.mdf`

Then, I had to edit one of its properties which was `Copy to Output Directory`. Its new value is now `Copy if Newer` and now my datas are well saved in the database.